# root cause of data too large in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am struggling to find the exact cause of the problem :

```
"type": "circuit_breaking_exception",
        "reason": "[fielddata] Data too large, data for [_id] would be [1704048152/1.5gb], which is larger than the limit of [1704040857/1.5gb]",
        "bytes_wanted": 1704048152,
        "bytes_limit": 1704040857,
        "durability": "PERMANENT"
```

It happened on my aws elastic search server, I thought memory might be an issue so on my local laptop I assigned -xms tp 32 mb and -xmx to 64 mb and tried inserting data in my index after around 1 00 000 records I got error :

```
circuit_breaking_exception
"reason": "[parent] Data too large
```

I was not able to get exact same error as that I got on AWS elastic search
I reproduce the problem I inserted more than 3500000 records but still, I am not getting that exception on my local

I am new to elastic search and I want to know what changes do I need to make so that I can avoid this problem on AWS elastic search

The configuration for AWS elastic search is :
Elasticsearch version7.4
Instance type (data)c5.xlarge.elasticsearch
EBS volume size60 GiB
Max clause count: 1024
Field data cache allocation: unbounded (default)

let me If more details are required

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding elasticsearch circuit\_breaking\_exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121024/understanding-elasticsearch-circuit-breaking-exception)

Comment: this has to do with parent circuit breaker and I am facing circuit breaking for fielddata

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned field data circuit breaker is being taken into account when estimating the amount of memory a field will need in order to be loaded into the JVM heap. It prevents the field data loading by raising an exception if the operation heap would exceed the limit. By default, it's configured to 40% of the maximum JVM heap. It can be configured too (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html#fielddata-circuit-breaker) here also related settings you should be aware of: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-fielddata.html

It seems, that the node is overloaded. Increase the JVM heap. If not feasible add another nodes in order to distribute the shards over more instanes.